# Extract rotation matrix out of a given rotation matrix and a defined rotation

Tags: python, matrix, rotation, robotics, vision

as you can see in the picture below, I have a given rotation matrix R_given (from rightmost to leftmost coordinate system), and I know the rotation matrix R_around_z, which is a easy rotation around the z_axis of the rightmost coordinate system.

The rotation matrices are as below:

```
R_given = np.array([[-0.9993, -0.0172, 0.0340],
                    [0.0099, -0.9785, -0.2062],
                    [0.0368, -0.2057, 0.9779]])

R_around_z = np.array([[-1, 0, 0],
                       [0, -1, 0],
                       [0, 0, 1]])
```

Is there any chance, to get the searched rotation matrix R_searched, which I would like to find, based on the two given matrices?

I am using Python and NumPy.

Thank you in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After writing the post and thinking about the problem, I actually found the answer by myself:

```
R_given = R_around_z * R_searched
```

and this gives:

```
R_searched = R_around_z_transposed * R_given
```

as general property of the rotation matrix is `R_invert = R_transpose`